# Replace Inline with sed, but also print output

Tags: unix, sed, replace

I am trying to inline modify a file, e.g.

```
sed -i -e 's/^bantime  = 600/bantime  = 86400/' /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf
```

I want to also output the results of this change to a log file.  The results could be anything, but ideally I would like some positive affirmation that a change was made.

Comment: Your one-liner appears to only print the change, not modify the file.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to get `sed -i` (inline sed) to print its progress to standard output, whether or not a change is made:

```
$ echo 'bantime = 600' > jail.conf
$ sed -i -e 's/^bantime = 300/bantime = 86400/g; w /dev/stdout' jail.conf
bantime = 86400
$ cat jail.conf
bantime = 86400
```

If you run the above command repeatedly without resetting `jail.conf`, then no changes will be made, but `sed` will still print the same output.

To print only *changed* lines, delete the semicolon in the above line. For example:

```
$ echo 'asdf\nbantime = 600' > jail.conf
$ echo 'a second line of text' >> jail.conf
$ sed -i -e 's/^bantime = 600/bantime = 86400/g w /dev/stdout' jail.conf
bantime = 86400
$ cat jail.conf
bantime = 86400
a second line of text
```

Finally, to save a backup, you can pass an extension to the `-i` switch:

```
$ echo 'asdf\nbantime = 600' > jail.conf
$ echo 'a second line of text' >> jail.conf
$ sed -i .old -e 's/^bantime = 600/bantime = 86400/g w /dev/stdout' jail.conf
bantime = 86400
$ cat jail.conf
bantime = 86400
another line of text
$ cat jail.conf.old
bantime = 600
another line of text
```

Comment: Thank you!  The first script prints the entire file (not very helpful); however, the second script block ("To print only _changed_ lines...") is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Christian, glad to hear! I learned a few things about sed in the process of answering :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
awk -i inplace 'sub(/^bantime  = 600/,"bantime  = 86400"){ print "Replaced line", NR, $0 |"cat>&2" } 1' /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf
```

The above uses GNU awk for inplace editing (just like GNU sed does with `-i`) and can print whatever message you like to stderr (or wherever else you prefer by modifying `cat>&2`) every time it does a substitution.

Comment: You could use `> "/dev/stderr"` instead of piping to `cat`, could you not?

Comment: Yes but then it wouldn't be portable to all UNIX boxes.